# Condition: Logical state of multi-bit packed array

Tags: logic, verilog

The configuration below

```
reg [3:0] myreg;

always@(...) begin
...
    if(myreg) begin <events> end ...
end
```

How reference to "myreg" in condition without referring specific bit and logical operation between bits in packed array will be handled?

**Edit: Would you please provide where this behavior you explained is documented?** As this semantic structure is allowed, I guess there should be some documentation about it... Thank you!

**Edit 1: Thanks for all your answers so far. Let's refocus on the following two points:**

- Why you believe logical value of (myreg) is reduction OR (not AND for example) - is there standard guideline? Let's turn off common sense and our feeling of "right" and "wrong" - these are not the matters we can base our conclusions on in mathematics/cybernetics.
- is it true that "it may behave differently with another simulator" - or in the real life?
  This strikes me because (a) I can not find document which states that it MUST be a reduction OR, and (b) that Quartus (which I use) does not give any warning or error for the syntax above.

Comment: I thought it a good question and have voted it up. I wouldn't worry too much, the judging of questions around here seems to be arbitrary, to put it mildly.

Comment: Regarding "Let's turn off common sense and our feeling of "right" and "wrong"" Id gave an implict example proving that is how the simulator was evaluating it. No gut feelings here only proof : http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3P76

Comment: Thanks. A number of implicit examples were already provided below, simulation is good but silicon is everything. I make silicon products, and references to simulation do not convince me because I will be ultimately responsible for results in silicon.

Comment: I make silicon too, but we are on a programmers site for software. Nothing wrong with asking about verilog here but you never mentioned about synthesis in the question so answers have not been targeted at that. Your initial question was a little confusing, some times it takes us a while to get the correct grammar so edits are good. your initial question was how is this handled, not what is the official specification of how this is evaluated and synthesised.

Comment: Morgan, you are absolutely right, thank you, sometimes you understand what you really need to know after several iterations of asking :)

Comment: It is worth remembering that no ASIC tools come with a guarantee.  They all try to implement the Spec, contain bugs and might not have implemented all of it, they struggle to keep up with the new language specs. Often RTL first then synthesisers a few years later. SO just because it is documented syntax does not mean it is synthesisable or will synthesise correctly. Simulating RTL to gate level checks that the synthesis tool logic matches the RTL simulators output.

Answer (score 0):

From this [EDA Playground example](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3P76) VCS 2014.2 is interpreting :

```
if (myreg) begin
  ...
```

as an OR bit reduction of myreg ie:

```
if ( |myreg == 1'b1) begin
  ...
```

As Greg found the relevant (SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012 Standard) section of the [LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) is Section 12.4

> it evaluates to false (that is, has a zero value or the value is x or z),

The code supplied `if (myreg)` is valid but given x's or z's will evaluate to false rather than propagating x's you may find a difference between RTL and gate level simulations if you use un-initialised registers, the initial x's will evaluate to false rather than potentially being 1 and evaluating to true.

Comment: Morgan, my point asking the question was if Quartus (in my case) does not give any warning or error then this should be valid construction, and should be regulated by some standard/guideline. If you think that "it may behave differently with another simulator" then what I experience seems to be a bug of Quartus, and normally it should throw at least warning.

Comment: I did say I could not find it not that it was not there. Just because something is a valid construction in Verilog does not mean you should use it in synthesisable RTL. Especially now that you have seen how it can handle x's during simulation. ie it resolves the x to false instead of propogating it, that alone would indicate to me that this type of construct is unsuitable for synthesis.

Comment: I agree that it is bad idea to use it. I would expect development tools telling it to me, e.g. throwing warning suggesting "are you meant |myreg[3:0]?". There's no worse things than assumptions and implications. Quartus assumes that I want to perform reduction OR, and my question - WHY it assumes so? If I just forgot.did mistake not putting index there so that it looks "myreg[2]"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Morgan is correct Xillinx ISE and Questasim is doing same, When I synthesis the following code.

```
module aa( input clk,
           input rst_n,
           input [4:0] my_reg,
           output reg chk
         );

always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
begin
  if (!rst_n) begin
    chk <= 1'bz;
  end  else begin
    if (my_reg) begin
      chk <= 1'b1;
    end
    else begin
      chk <= 1'b0;
    end
  end
end

endmodule
```

You can see here schematic view,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Verilog should behave like this:

```
myreg | result | comment
------|--------|--------
0000  | 1'b0   | FALSE - all bit bits are zero
0010  | 1'b1   | TRUE  - at least one bit is one
001X  | 1'b1   | TRUE  - at least one bit is one
000X  | 1'bX   | FALSE - we don't know whether all bits are zero or not
                         and if interprets 1'bX as FALSE
```

Comment: @Anonymous from a Doulos slide.

Comment: Matthew, please no offence but I can draw a number of different slides. Is there any slide/document about it released by authorized organization or committee, e.g. IEEE?

Comment: Doulos are the preferred (by me and I think many others) trainers of Verilog, your right to question a random slide on the internet, but I do trust Doulos, it based on the language spec and realworld use.

Comment: @Anonymous I think Greg has answered that below. I don't claim it's clear, but it is there in the LRM. I would recommend `if (my_reg != 4'b0)` over `if (my_reg)` because it is more readable: you are not expecting the reader to have every detail of the LRM available in their head.

Answer (score 0):

`if(myreg)` is the same as `if(myreg != 0)` according to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 12.4 *Conditional if–else statement*

> The *conditional statement* (or *if–else* statement) is used to make a
>   decision about whether a statement is executed. Formally, the syntax
>   is given in Syntax 12-2.
>
> ```
> conditional_statement ::=  // from A.6.6  
> [ unique_priority ] if ( cond_predicate ) statement_or_null  
>  { else if ( cond_predicate ) statement_or_null }  
>  [ else statement_or_null ]  
> unique_priority ::= unique | unique0 | priority  
> cond_predicate ::= expression_or_cond_pattern { &&& expression_or_cond_pattern }  
> expression_or_cond_pattern ::=  expression | cond_pattern 
> cond_pattern ::= expression matches pattern
> ```
>
> Syntax 12-2—Syntax for if–else statement (excerpt from Annex A)
>   If the *cond_predicate*  expression evaluates to true (that is, has a nonzero known value), the first statement shall be executed. If it evaluates to false (that is, has a zero value or the value is *x* or *z*), the first statement shall not execute. If there is an else statement and the *cond_predicate* expression is false, the else statement shall be executed. Because the numeric value of the *if* expression is tested for being zero, certain shortcuts are possible. For example, the following two statements
>   express the same logic:
>
> ```
> if(expression)  
> if(expression != 0)
> ```

Note the LRM is checking if the expression is a nonzero value. It is not constraining the width or even considering if it is a signed type. Negative numbers would be be true, only zero is false.

Synthesizers may do bit-wise compression which is equivalent logic as comparing to zero.

Comment: Greg, question is exactly about how synthesizer uses multi-bit packed array in case IF statement is fed with multiple bits. If you look at Matthew's answer, he says that value of 'bX also gives FALSE.

Comment: @Anonymous, the LRM states 'bX is FALSE, in the quote "it evaluates to false (that is, has a zero value or the value is x or z)". Now in synthesis there is no real X. An X from synthesis means conflicting drivers on the same net; causing a short between supply and ground. `myreg != 0` and `|myreg` (OR reduction) are mathematically equivalent.